# Proving that $f$ is analytic if $f$ and $z f(z)$ are harmonic

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-functions

If $f$ is harmonic and $zf(z)$ is harmonic, then $f$ is analytic. Please help me prove this. Thanks.

Comment: All harmonic functions are analytic. You can show this easily by looking at the power series of your function

Comment: @BrentJ: By saying "analytic", I think he means holomorphic.

Comment: Yeah, seems to be a question of translation and/or definitions.

Comment: @richard Aren't all analytic functions holomorphic?

Comment: @BrentJ Demepends on the domain, of course. Analytic function $\mathbb C$ are holomorphic.

Comment: @BrentJ: If you agree with analytic=holmorphic, then harmonic functions may not be analytic.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I was assuming this was in C

Comment: @richard That's a good point, I jumped in a little too fast while assuming too much about this problem

Comment: this question is in the book Banach spaces of analytic functions, in page 40

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to show $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation. We will use the [Wirtinger derivatives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger_derivatives)
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}-i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right)\qquad \frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\right).
$$
To begin with, observe that for $C^2$ functions, $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial y}$ commute, so the Laplacian $\Delta$ is then given by
$$\Delta=4 \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \overline{z}\partial z}.$$

Denote $g(z):=zf(z)$. Since $f$ is assumed to be harmonic, it is in particular $C^2$, like $g$.

First, we compute
$$
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z}=f+z\frac{\partial f }{\partial z}
$$
whence
$$
\frac{\partial^2 g}{\partial \overline{z}\partial z}=\frac{\partial f }{\partial \overline{z}}+\frac{\partial z }{\partial \overline{z}}\frac{\partial f }{\partial z}+z\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \overline{z}\partial z}=\frac{\partial f }{\partial \overline{z}}+z\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial \overline{z}\partial z}.
$$
We've only used the product rule for $\frac{\partial}{\partial z}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \overline{z}}$, and the fact that $\frac{\partial z}{\partial \overline{z}}=0$, which is easy to check.
So 
$$ 
\frac{\partial f }{\partial \overline{z}}=\frac{1}{4}(\Delta g-z\Delta f).
$$
It follows that if $f$ and $g$ are both harmonic, that is $\Delta f=\Delta g=0$, then $f$ satisfies the [Cauchy-Riemann equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations): 
$$
\frac{\partial f }{\partial \overline{z}}=0\qquad\iff\qquad \frac{\partial f }{\partial x}+i\frac{\partial f }{\partial y}=0.
$$
As you can [see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_function), a real differentiable function on $\mathbb{C}$ is holomorphic if and only if it satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equation. So $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: sir thanks, but is this solution in detail

Comment: I want to know how this answer is solved step by step

Comment: @MatemaTika Well, this is already a step by step answer. What other steps do you need?